# Cant get NewsApi data to show up in React

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

I can't get my News Api data to appear...
Error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
from the news-container file."

I think there is something wrong with the way I am extracting the data from New Api.

## news-api.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getNews = async () => {
  const result = await axios
    .get("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-12-15&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=...")
    .then(function(response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
    });
  return result;
};
```

## news-container.js file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getNews } from "../news-api";
import NewsCard from "./NewsCard.js";

function NewsContainer() {
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getNews().then(data => setNews(data));
  }, []);
  return news.map(article => <NewsCard props={article} />);
}

export default NewsContainer;
```

## news-card.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./card.css";

function NewsCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="cardWrapper">
      <div className="cards">
        <img src="article.urlToImage" alt="" />
        <h2>{props.article.title}</h2>
        <p>{props.article.description}text</p>
        <a className="aColor" href={props.article.url}>
          Read More
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewsCard;
```

Comment: Kindly donot post your API credentials in the question, I have submitted an edit for this.

Comment: The full API key is still in the edit history, so it's better to just revoke that key and generate a new one.

Comment: @cyberAnn are you getting data in api request response?

Comment: @VahidAkhtar yes I am getting a response, I can see objects, but only before I map through the data.

Comment: @cyberAnn is it array or object?

Comment: it is an array with objects.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this:

```
return  news.map(article =>
  <NewsCard  props={article} />)
}
```

to this:

```
return  news.article.map(item =>
  <NewsCard  props={item} />)
}
```

because you set object in state not the articles array. just check your response.

Comment: I made the changes but I still get the same error messages

Comment: you need to do that every where. if still have a problem create sanbox and json object of response for me , so i can help you.

Comment: it is only in one place...  I don't know how to create a sandbox... the response data looks like this:  www.newsapi.org  is there anyway to review my code on github?

Comment: you can implement your code in here : https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to access the Axios response's `data` to get the actual response payload.

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getNews = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-12-15&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=...");
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: I made the changes and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Without knowing the shape of the response data, it's hard to help further.

Comment: the response data appears if i remove the map(). the data looks like the data on: newsapi.org